# When using a UnboundedPriorityMailbox in Akka, is order guaranteed for messages with the same priority?

Tags: akka, priority-queue

As per title. If two messages are given the same priority, will their respective order be guaranteed to be preserved when using a UnboundedPriorityMailbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is backed by Java's [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) so it has its semantics, if you want other semantics, it's quite easy to [implement your own mailbox type](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/dispatchers.html#Creating_your_own_Mailbox_type).

Comment: Not preserving order of messages of same priority is, if nothing else, unexpected. I can see a number of use cases where you want higher priority messages to move to the front of the queue, but on a busy actor, these semantics mean that messages may be potentially starved forever... I guess I will have to roll my own.

Comment: Using priorities _at all_ actually means that messages might be starved forever. OTOH I was also initially surprised. Looking forward to see your PriorityQueue implementation!

Comment: I'm assuming my answer was the golden ticket for this question?